# How to find duplicates in a 2d list - Python 3

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, counter

```
list = [['P', True, 1], ['U', True, 3], ['P', True, 4], ['P', True, 5], ['Y', True, 6]]
```

I'm trying to make the game Hangman and I'm trying to find the letters that appear more than once in this 2d list and get their index. The first value is the letter, the second value is whether or not they've already find that letter and the third value is the x-coordinate. I have tried so many things and none of them have worked.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: `I have tried so many things`: Like what? This looks like an XY question. Post your whole code so that we can suggest a possibly better way of storing this information.

Comment: I'm trying to get the index of the repeated letters

Comment: The question was clear enough and was closed in error, though any question that involves Hangman is somebody asking the internet to do their homework for them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are trying to find the index of the repeated letters. Here's what I tried. See if this works. If you are looking for the duplicate of the entire second list, then the code will change. I am trying to find the duplicate of just the letter in the second list. For ex: P is repeated 3 times.

```
list = [['P', True, 1],
        ['U', True, 3],
        ['P', True, 4],
        ['P', True, 5],
        ['Y', True, 6]]

x = [list[i][0][0] for i in range (len(list))]

for i in range (len(x)):
    if (x[i] in x[:i]) or (x[i] in x[i+1:]): print (x[i], i)
```

Output:

```
P 0
P 2
P 3
```

Comment: This output does not make any sense. What does `2, 3, 3` mean?

Comment: I am just giving @Anthony Lizarraga a way to identify which index value has the letters duplicated. I am not clear on his question. Just providing options for Antony to see that there are ways to access the index.  In this case, element 2, and 3 have value P. Thats what I am trying to say.

Comment: Element 0 is also "P" but you don't print that.

Comment: sorry. Updated code to print all instances of the value

    x = [list[i][0][0] for i in range (len(list))]

    for i in range (len(x)):
        if (x[i] in x[:i]) or (x[i] in x[i+1:]): print (x[i], i)

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried solving this for days and I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Start here maybe. This will tell you the index at least.

```
list = [['P', True, 1], ['U', True, 3], ['P', True, 4], ['P', True, 5], ['Y', True, 6]]
count = -1
for i in list:
    count += 1
    print(count,i)
```

returns

```
0 ['P', True, 1]
1 ['U', True, 3]
2 ['P', True, 4]
3 ['P', True, 5]
4 ['Y', True, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, assuming I understand the requirements:

```
import collections

# note that I added another duplicate - 'U'
l = [['P', True, 1], ['U', True, 3], ['P', True, 4], ['P', True, 5], ['Y', True, 6], ["U", True, 7]]
simplified_list = [i[0] for i in l]
counter = collections.Counter([i for i in simplified_list])
duplicates = [k for k,v in counter.items() if v > 1]

res = [inx for inx, letter in enumerate(simplified_list) if letter in duplicates]
print (res)
```

The output, for the above list, is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```