# Python - 2D list - find duplicates in one column and sum values in another column

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a 2D list that contains soccer player names, the number of times they scored a goal, and the number of times they attempted a shot on goal, respectively.

`player_stats = [['Adam', 5, 10], ['Kyle', 12, 18], ['Jo', 20, 35], ['Adam', 15, 20], ['Charlie', 31, 58], ['Jo', 6, 14], ['Adam', 10, 15]]`

From this list, I'm trying to return another list that shows only one instance of each player with their respective *total* goals and *total* attempts on goal, like so:

`player_stats_totals = [['Adam', 30, 45], ['Kyle', 12, 18], ['Jo', 26, 49], ['Charlie', 31, 58]]`

After searching on Stack Overflow I was able to learn (from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63007734/how-to-find-duplicates-in-a-2d-list-python-3)) how to return the indexes of the duplicate players

```
x = [player_stats[i][0] for i in range (len(player_stats))]

for i in range (len(x)):
    if (x[i] in x[:i]) or (x[i] in x[i+1:]): print (x[i], i)
```

but got stuck on how to proceed thereafter and if indeed this method is strictly relevant for what I need(?)

What's the most efficient way to return the desired list of totals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary to accumulate the values for a given player:

```
player_stats = [['Adam', 5, 10], ['Kyle', 12, 18], ['Jo', 20, 35], ['Adam', 15, 20], ['Charlie', 31, 58], ['Jo', 6, 14], ['Adam', 10, 15]]

lookup = {}
for player, first, second in player_stats:
    
    # if the player has not been seen add a new list with 0, 0 
    if player not in lookup:
        lookup[player] = [0, 0]
    
    # get the accumulated total so far 
    first_total, second_total = lookup[player]
    
    # add the current values to the accumulated total, and update the values 
    lookup[player] = [first_total + first, second_total + second]

# create the output in the expected format
res = [[player, first, second] for player, (first, second) in lookup.items()]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[['Adam', 30, 45], ['Kyle', 12, 18], ['Jo', 26, 49], ['Charlie', 31, 58]]
```

A more advanced, and *pythonic*, version is to use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

player_stats = [['Adam', 5, 10], ['Kyle', 12, 18], ['Jo', 20, 35],
                ['Adam', 15, 20], ['Charlie', 31, 58], ['Jo', 6, 14], ['Adam', 10, 15]]

lookup = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])
for player, first, second in player_stats:
    # get the accumulated total so far
    first_total, second_total = lookup[player]

    # add the current values to the accumulated total, and update the values
    lookup[player] = [first_total + first, second_total + second]

# create the output in the expected format
res = [[player, first, second] for player, (first, second) in lookup.items()]

print(res)
```

This approach has the advantage of *skipping* the initialisation. Both has approaches are O(n).

**Notes**

The expression:

```
res = [[player, first, second] for player, (first, second) in lookup.items()]
```

is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), equivalent to the following for loop:

```
res = []
for player, (first, second) in lookup.items():
    res.append([player, first, second])
```

Additionally, read [this](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/) for understanding unpacking.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate the detailed response with comments explaining the code. The output is precisely what I was looking for, hence the tick. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use a dictionary where the key is the player name and the value is a list containing [goals, shots].  Constructing it would look like this:

```
all_games_stats = {}
for stat in player_stats:
    player, goals, shots = stat
    if player not in all_games_stats:
        all_games_stats[player] = [goals, shots]
    else:
        stat_list = all_games_stats[player]
        stat_list[0] += goals
        stat_list[1] += shots
```

Then, if you want to represent the players and their stats as a list, you would do:
list(all_games_stats.items())

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and help. When I ran the code, it returned what looks like tuples within a list: [('Adam', [30, 45]), ('Kyle', [12, 18]), ('Jo', [26, 49]), ('Charlie', [31, 58])]. I would want the return to be lists so I can manipulate them later if required and from my newbie knowledge of Python, I’m not sure that I can do that with tuples.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list to a dictionary. (It can always be changed back once done) This works:

```
player_stats = [['Adam', 5, 10], ['Kyle', 12, 18], ['Jo', 
20, 35], ['Adam', 15, 20], ['Charlie', 31, 58], ['Jo', 6, 
14], ['Adam', 10, 15]]

new_stats = {}


for item in player_stats:
    if not item[0] in new_stats:
        new_stats[item[0]] = [item[1],item[2]]
    else:
        new_stats[item[0]][0] += item[1]
        new_stats[item[0]][1] += item[2]

print(new_stats)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your quick reply and offering a solution. When I ran your code it returned a dictionary `{'Adam': [30, 45], 'Kyle': [12, 18], 'Jo': [26, 49], 'Charlie': [31, 58]}`  and with a bit of research, I’m sure I would learn how to convert it back to a list. I awarded the tick to @Dani because the output was a list as I had wanted. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I might as well submit something, too.  Here's yet another method with some list comprehension worked in:

```
# Unique values to new dictionary with goal and shots on goal default entries 
agg_stats = dict.fromkeys(set([p[0] for p in player_stats]), [0, 0])

# Iterate over the player stats list
for player in player_stats:
    # Set entry to sum of current and next stats values for the corresponding player.
    agg_stats[player[0]] = [sum([agg_stats.get(player[0])[i], stat]) for i, stat in enumerate(player[1:])]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for submitting your method. When I ran your code I didn't get an output. I'm sure in time, I would have been able to figure out how to output the list as intended - I trust it's straightforward, though being new to Python it would have required perhaps another post. @Dani's answer provided the solution I was looking for.

Comment: I now see that adding `print(agg_stats)` returns a dictionary with the total values `{'Adam': [30, 45], 'Jo': [26, 49], 'Kyle': [12, 18], 'Charlie': [31, 58]}`

Comment: What's the point of using `sum([x, y])` instead of `x + y`?

Comment: @KellyBundy No point, really.  Either works.  Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way, storing the whole *triples* (including the name) in the dict and updating them:

```
stats = {}
for name, goals, attempts in player_stats:
    entry = stats.setdefault(name, [name, 0, 0])
    entry[1] += goals
    entry[2] += attempts
player_stats_totals = list(stats.values())
```

And for fun a solution with complex numbers, which makes adding nice but requires annoying conversion back:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tmp = defaultdict(complex)
for name, *stats in player_stats:
    tmp[name] += complex(*stats)
player_stats_totals = [[name, int(stats.real), int(stats.imag)]
                       for name, stats in tmp.items()]
```

Comment: Yes indeed, by adding `print(player_stats_totals)` it produces the desired result, thank you very much for providing a solution.